# Call WCF service host directly

Tags: wcf, host

I'm hosting a WCF service inside a winform app. I want to monitor when somebody calls the service to a textbox on the form like:

2:23 Method X called params(x, y)
2:24 Method Y called params(z)

I am using a service host for WCF and inside my concrete class I have created some delegates and events. I just cant seem to wire the events up because my object is of type ServiceHost not my object.

Any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are few ways. You can make those events static.

or

you can make your service a singleton then you can say

```
MyService service =new MyService();
service.EventA += EventHandeler();
new ServiceHost(service).Open();
```

In addition when your web service updates UI elements you may need to make sure the right thread does the work. That applies to WPF and winforms. [Synchronization Contexts in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163321.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Vitalik, passing in an instance of the class to WCF to wire up to is exactly what I was looking for!